# Can't save Visual Studio 2010 Setup project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

When I create a new Setup Project and accept the default location (or another drive; it doesn't matter), I get an immediate popup to `Save File As` with the full path and filename (Setup1.vdproj). If I click `Save`, I get an error saying "Could not find file [full path]\Setup1.vdproj.

Changing the location, removing the path, changing the type from UTF-8 to Text or Unicode all make no difference. I can create any other type of project (except setup ones) normally and without issue, including creating a project in the same solution that was created to house the setup project!

It's probably something simple, just wondering if anyone has any ideas. Thanks!

Windows 7 SP1 (on a domain, where I am the domain admin).
VS 2010 Premium v10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
.NET v4.5.50938 SP1Rel

Comment: Do you have access rights to the directory where it's trying to save the project? (It may be a daft question, but it doesn't hurt to check the obvious).

Comment: Yeah I do, as I said I can create other projects in the same folder after the setup failed to save. Always a wise question to ask!

Comment: Unusual problem.  Otherwise the core reason that .vdproj setup projects are no longer supported in later VS versions.  Too many quirky problems like this, they gave up on trying to maintain it.  There is no future, cut your losses soon.

Comment: We plan to move to Wix or similar when we upgrade to VS2014, but for now I just needed to make an installer for a service I'm creating.

Comment: Currently I think I may have worked around the problem by copying a .vdproj from another project and tweaking it a bit, but I have also discovered a coworker can create the project just fine, so that will most likely be the final solution. I just wanted to work out if this was something simple or not. Seems not.